# Set column to rownames for a list of sublist of dataframes in r

Tags: r

I have a list of 6 sublists, each sublist contains 3 dataframes.

I want to set the row names of the dataframes to a column in that datagram.

```
list_1 <- list(df1, df2, df3)
list_2 <- lapply(list_1, function(x) split(x, x$Type))
```

I try to rename the rows of the data frames with `lapply`

```
lapply(list_2, function(x) column_to_rownames(x, var=x$Rows))

print(df1)
      Rows       A
1    Baseline    4
2    Sample1     5
3    Sample2     8
4    Sample3     6
5    AASHTO      9
6    Mean        3

print(df2)
      Rows       A
1    Baseline    4
2    Sample1     7
3    Sample2     8
4    Sample3     6
5    AASHTO      4
6    Mean        3

print(df3)
      Rows       A
1    Baseline    3
2    Sample1     5
3    Sample2     6
4    Sample3     6
5    AASHTO      5
6    Mean        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested list in `list_2`. Try  `unlist`ing one level

```
list_3 <- lapply(unlist(list_2, recursive = FALSE), function(x) 
               tibble::column_to_rownames(x, var= "Rows"))
```

Or using only base R :

```
list_3 <- lapply(unlist(list_2, recursive = FALSE), function(x) 
                 {rownames(x) <- x$Rows;x$Rows <- NULL;x})
```